# Cloudfront default domain works, but getting "NoSuchWebsiteConfiguration" on alternate domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm able to load my website via the default https://example.cloudfront.net domain, which I'm assuming verifies my S3 bucket permissions are done right.

But after adding my example.example.com domain to the distribution setting, and adding the CNAME in my domain provider (Google Domains), I get "NoSuchWebsiteConfiguration" error when I navigate to example.example.com.

The specific error message is: "The specified bucket does not have a website configuration". This does not make sense to me as it seems like a S3 error instead of CloudFront. But the S3 bucket should be configured correctly since the default CloudFront domain works.

Please advice.

Comment: Can you show your origin configuration? Are you using S3 origin or custom origin for your bucket?

Comment: It's a S3 origin generated automatically when I created the distribution.

Comment: Ok after waiting for like an hour, everything just magically worked. Now I'm thoroughly confused.